# iPhone SDK: How to record voices with ambient noise suppression?

Tags: iphone, core-audio, noise-reduction

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how I would minimize ambient noise while recording someone speaking using the iPhone SDK Core Audio? I'm guessing a band-pass filter that eliminates any frequencies above and below the human vocal range might work. I have no idea how I would implement band filters on audio in the SDK though. The optimum solution would be one that eliminates the noise from the stream before it is written to memory/disk.

Comment: Noise, by its random nature, is inherently a difficult thing to remove from audio or any other signal. While you can remove the apparent noise in a recording, it will affect the signal in unpredictable ways. Consider all the archivists and recording engineers and their constant battle with noise.

Comment: Have you been able to reduce background noise while recording?if so please give some ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need to implement an [adaptive filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_filter) and a [voice activity detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection). In periods where there is no speech you would collect ambient noise and use this to drive the adaptive filter.

Comment: R-->can you provide me any codes for implementing the adaptive filter algorithm?

Comment: @Warrior: adaptive filters are non-trivial to implement - I suggest you read a good book on the subject, e.g . http://www.amazon.com/Adaptive-Filter-Theory-Simon-Haykin/dp/0130901261 or failing that at least Google for LMS etc and learn some of the theory before trying an implementation

Answer (score 2):

Have a search for "spectral subtraction" which a technique of analyzing a sample of what you're calling background noise, and then subtracting it from the the regular signal.  Yes, you will always get some artifacts.  It's a tradeoff.